# Check if website checkbox in checked with excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to make a VBA that can read the HTML and checked if a specific check box is checked and write either check or unchecked in a cell. But I am having difficulties with VBA as I do not use it as often, any advise will be appreciated.

HTML

```
<input id="foo1" type="checkbox" name="Device" value="iPad" 
checked="checked">
```

VBA

```
Sub getValue()
      Dim IE      As Object: Set IE = 
      CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim ws      As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Country As String

With IE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate ws.Range("A3").Value

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until .readyState = 4

End With

 Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Dim document
 document.getElementById("checkBox(iPad)")
 Item(0).Checked = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to share the website?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector("#foo1").getAttribute("checked") ="checked"
```

I am not sure, without an URL to test with whether there is `.Checked` property you can evaluate for `True` ( `ie.document.querySelector("#foo1").Checked`)

Without more HTML hard to say if this will be able to access the required element. There may be forms/iframes/frames to negotiate.

Comment: Any feedback at all please?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with looping all the input elements on the website until you find the one with the right name, this will of course be slower then a `querySelector`, but can be usefull if you need to change multiple input elements.

```
Dim objCollection as Object
Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0

'Loop through all elements and find the checkbox
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "Device" Then
        objCollection(i).Checked = False
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

If you only have 1 checkbox i would no doubt go with a `querySelector` as [@QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr)